# Powershell text/html templates that include loops

Tags: loops, templates, powershell

I know how to do a string replacement from inside a text template, something simple like

**text file**

```
Hello ${name}
```

**posh**

```
[string] $name = "World"
$template = Get-Content 'c:\temp\docs\template.txt'
$expanded = $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($template)
$expanded
```

**Output Expected**

```
Hello World
```

---

This is all well and good, but what if I need something more advanced?

**text file**

```posh
<div>title</div>
<ul>
    $(${points} | % { $_ })
</ul>
```

**posh**

```posh
[string[]]$points = "First Point", "Second Point"
$template = Get-Content 'c:\temp\docs\template.txt' -force
$expanded = Invoke-Expression $template
$expanded
```

**output expected**

```
<div>title<div>
<ul>
    <li>First Point</li>
    <li>Second Point</li>
</ul>
```

What do I need to do to create loop templates inside a text file?

---

EDIT:

here's the concept I'm going for as far as the template would be concerned.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="page-header">
        <h1>${name}</h1>
        <p class="lead">${synopsis}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h2> Syntax </h2>
        </div>
        <pre>
<code>${syntax}</code>
        </pre>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <h2> Detailed Description </h2>
        <div>${description}</div>
    </div>
    {ifdef links}
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <h2> Related Commands </h2>
        <div>${links}</div>
    </div>
    {endif links}
    {ifdef parameters}
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <h2> Parameters </h2>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Required?</th>
                <th>Pipeline Input</th>
                <th>Default Value</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                {foreach param in ${parameters}}
                <td>$($param.Name)</td>
                <td>$($param.Description)</td>
                <td>$(param.Required)</td>
                <td>$(param.PipelineInput)</td>
                <td>$(param.DefaultValue)</td>
                {endforeach}
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    {endif parameters}
    {ifdef notes}
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <h2> Notes </h2>
        <div>${notes}</div>
    </div>
    {endif notes}
    {ifdef examples}
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <h2> Examples </h2>
        {foreach example in ${examples}}
        <h3> Example </h3>
        <pre>${example.code}</pre>
        <div>${example.remarks}</div>
        {endforeach}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Would you take it as cheating to perform the loop in PowerShell then insert the string using a simple replacement like in your first example. As that would work with your second example

Comment: yeah, I'm considering it, and will if I must, but I'm *ass*uming that there must be a way within the template :S

Comment: Nice comment formatting :)

Comment: I would also like to point out that expanding strings and executed code from files are two different things. What if someone put malicious code in your template file? You could blindly execute it. Realistic? No. Possible? Yes.

Comment: I understand the risks, but am not worried about it in this case. It's a part of a build pipeline whereby I'm documenting my powershell comments at build time before they're packaged into a nupkg.

Comment: I'm basically using [this example](http://poshcode.org/587) as a starting point, but am refactoring it to not use frames, and to be able to leverage bootstrap. The html is getting unwieldy, so I need a better way.

Comment: I've added a concept of how I'd like to approach the template.

Comment: Interesting idea. Will test further. If you made the template a large piece of code that gets outputted then I could see `Invoke-Expression` working...

Comment: I update my answer with something that might be of more use to you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am really interested in a good answer for this but I will expand on my suggestion in the comment. I'm sure you are capable of doing this yourself but this could be of value to someone.

If your file contained

```html
<div>title</div>
<ul>
${list}
</ul>
```

Then we could do this to populate the list

```powershell
$list = ("First Point", "Second Point" | ForEach-Object{"`t<li>$_</li>"}) -join "`r`n"
$template = Get-Content 'c:\temp\docs\template.txt' -raw
$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($template)
```

Yes I know this is not exactly what you are asking but it does have a similar result.

## Why not turn the whole file into code instead?

**Disclaimer:** I would like to point out that expanding strings and executed code from files are two different things. What if someone put malicious code in your template file? You could blindly execute it. Realistic problem? No. Possible catastrophe? Maybe.

I update a small part of your sample edit to prove the method. Yes the HTML is malformed and sucks. It exists to show what I mean.

**Sample File**

```powershell
'<div class="container-fluid">'
'    <div class="page-header">'
"        <h1>$name</h1>"
"        <p class=`"lead`">$synopsis</p>"
'    </div>'
'    <tr>'
foreach($param in $parameters){
"        <td>$($param.Name)</td>"
"        <td>$($param.Description)</td>"
}
'    </tr>'
```

I picked that snippet since you see a simple variable, simple variable in quotes and a loop structure. I have single quotes around most of the lines since they will just be sent as standard string output. So, with that, we use the following code:

```powershell
$name = "Matt"
$synopsis ="Ughhh... stuff"
$parameters = 1,2 | Foreach-object{[pscustomobject]@{Name="$_ Factory";Description="$_ Apples"}}

$template = Get-Content 'c:\temp\docs\template.txt' -raw
Invoke-Expression $template
```

Which nets the following, again *awful*, output.

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="page-header">
        <h1>Matt</h1>
        <p class="lead">Ughhh... stuff</p>
    </div>
    <tr>
        <td>1 Factory</td>
        <td>1 Apples</td>
        <td>2 Factory</td>
        <td>2 Apples</td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: This'll work I think. Much cleaner than what I'm working with now.

Comment: @ChaseFlorell well if nothing else comes up at least this could work. Meta programming is fun!

Comment: Thanks for the direction @Matt, I've shared my final solution on [my blog](https://chaseflorell.github.io/powershell/2015/04/27/how-to-generate-beautiful-powershell-documentation/)

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, and you have a good workaround, but I thought others might be interested in the answer. What you had in the original question was very close.

**This works**

**template.txt**

```
<div>title</div>
<ul>$(${points} | ForEach {
@"    
    <li>$_<\li>
"@
})
</ul>
```

**PowerShell**

```
$points = 'First Point', 'Second Point', 'Third Point'
$template = Get-Content 'template.txt' -Raw
$expanded = $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($template)
$expanded
```

**Output**

```
<div>title</div>
<ul>
    <li>First Point<\li>
    <li>Second Point<\li>
    <li>Third Point<\li>
</ul>
```

You got the one trick, using $( on the second line of the template to open an expression. But your expression didn't use the proper syntax. The second trick is to keep using `ExpandString` like you did in the working example you provided. Once the proper syntax is provided in the template, it will be correctly evaluated by `ExpandString` (because were using an interpolated strings expression). The output matches your expected output (except I left in "Third Point" which I added while testing and fixing the formatting).

Comment: this is what I was building back then https://github.com/ChaseFlorell/psDoc

Comment: this is the output it's designed to create https://futurestatemobile.github.io/poshBAR/

Comment: Nice. Came across this question while refactoring some code that could be improved by using a simple template system. I think using ExpandString will work for me. You're application needs more code and jamming all that into interpolated string sub-expressions is awkward so I see that's not the best choice for you.